# Reorder columns of a MediaWiki wiki table

Tags: open-source, mediawiki

A [MediaWiki wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTables) table looks like this:

```
{|
|a1
|b1
|-
|a2
|b2
|-
|a3
|b3
|}
```

It renders as:

```
a1    b1
a2    b2
a3    b3
```

Wikipedia editors often need to reorder columns (for instance alphabetically), because of renamings or when translating to a new language. Reordering is very error-prone, especially in tables with 15+ columns and 100+ lines.

**QUESTION:** Is there a tool that could reorder columns painlessly?

Requirements

- Open Source
- UI, script, command line, anything is OK
- Any OS is OK
- Not supporting the whole specification is OK, just the format seen in the example above is OK

Comment: I used to use http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Wiki_Table_Editor but AFAIK got broken with the latest versions of MW :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was no such software, so I created one, as open source (GPLv3):

https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/reorder-wikitable-columns

It is very user-unfriendly:

- bash script
- you have to edit code to specify what order you want
- no error handling

... so any other answer is very welcome!